# How can I check if a file/directory is on a fast drive like SSD?

Tags: linux, ssd, storage

I have a script which has a faster not-so-precise version and a slower thorough version (think recursive directory comparison or duplicate file search). I would like to run the slower version by default on volumes which have high seek penalty (conventional HDDs) and a faster version on volumes which are inherently fast (SSDs, RAM drives, etc.)

Is there something similar to [`DEVICE_SEEK_PENALTY_DESCRIPTOR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-device_seek_penalty_descriptor) in Win32 API that I could check in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from kernel 2.6.29, SSD disks are automatically detected, and you may verify this with:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
```

You should get 1 for hard disks and 0 for a SSD.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/228657/which-linux-filesystem-works-best-with-ssd#answer-550308